# In PostgreSQL, can you have "aliases" on the column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, informix

I am working on a legacy project where tables and columns have been through multiple naming conventions and it is a little difficult to find what is relevant.

I wish I could create aliases on the columns so that we can start to implement good practice for new development, while not impacting the old development.

Ideally, if I have table `customer` which has `customer_key` and `fname`, i could alias the first one to `id` and when i run

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_key = 1
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = 1
```

I get the same name.

I use both PostgreSQL and Informix, but this is more relevant to PostgreSQL here.

Comment: May be you should create views on problem tables?

Comment: We might start a dispute if `id`  instead of `customer_key` is a *good practice* :-)

Comment: We could start a dispute, I draft a quick example, but you're right...

Comment: Whatever the naming convention, `id` is *always* a very bad idea. Some daft middleware likes to use this, but don't fall for the anti-pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *create views* on problem tables, like that:

```
create view customers as
  select customer_key as id, 
         -- ... some other fields 
         fname as name 
    from customer
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I ws thinking of that but VIEWs are readonly and I do not know if the other applications are doing only SELECT...

Comment: @jgp: simple views like that are automatically updateable in the current Postgres version. And can be made updateable easily in previous versions.

Comment: Very interesting idea indeed! I need to give it a try!